# Что значит и какова этимология слова "колпачить"?

Tags: значения, этимология

Слышал эту фразу в контексте произведения человеком ненужной суеты или глупых действий, вызванных нервозностью момента.

Есть еще связанное определение для человека, который "колпачит" - говорят, у него "колпак до небес" или (более сильная форма) "вакуумный колпак".

Comment: Многие словари (Ефремовой, Ушакова, Малый академический словарь) трактуют "колпачить" как производное от "околпачить" - обманывать, дурачить и т.д. Вариант толкования который вы приводите найти не удалось.

Comment: @Artemix спасибо за информацию!

Comment: "Колпак до небес" - поиск в Гугле выдает 4 результата, включая этот вопрос. Видимо, какой-то локальный сленг.

Comment: Можно еще предположить что здесь есть какая-то ассоциация с "колбасить" - "его колбасит".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно, как земетил @Artemix, значения слова `колпачить` -

> обманывать, дурачить.

[image]

[image]

[Источник](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: совсем не то значение, что я имел в виду, но это, несомненно, ответ